# Adding input fields to a table using Form Array and *ngFor - Angular 2/5

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor, formarray, formgroups

I'm a beginner at Angular 5 trying to add input fields dynamically to a table with a form array.
I've used *ngFor inside the tr tag and the sample code is as follows:

HTML File:

```
          <table class="table">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>F1</th>
                      <th>F2</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <form novalidate role="form" [formGroup]="caseinfo">
              <div formArrayName="caseRows">
              <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let caserow of caseinfo.controls.caseRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" >

                      <td>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="caselpn">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="casesku">
                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
            </div>
            </form>

          </table>
```

TS File:

```
  initFormCase()
  {
    this.caseinfo = this.fb.group({
    caseRows: this.fb.array([this.initCaseRows()]) // here
    });
  }

  initCaseRows() {
    return this.fb.group({
    caselpn:[null, Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
    ])],
    casesku:[null, Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
    ])]
    });
    }
```

This is what my output looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd5A1.png

Expected output: 
Input field 1 under F1 column. and 
Input field 2 under F2 column.

Note: 
I tried replacing the ngFor inside the tbody too. No luck.
Thanks in advance!
Sorry, can't post images as I have low rep points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML structure is wrong, try to update it as below and check

```
<form novalidate role="form" [formGroup]="caseinfo">
    <div formArrayName="caseRows">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>F1</th>
                    <th>F2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let caserow of caseinfo.controls.caseRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="caselpn">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="casesku">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I guess the structure was my problem. It started working fine after I made the modifications you suggested. Thanks a ton!